# C# class library export as COM, errors during MIDL compilation

Tags: c#, winapi, com, interop

I'm trying to create a COM library from a C# library I have.  In order to do this I've defined my C# class as follows:

```
[Guid("830D0BFA-8045-455B-AAB7-2A7D4A16455C")]    
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IMyInterface
{
        uint Start();
}

[Guid("22B91F20-1CC3-4276-BB51-0AE75D7DA5BB")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyInterface_Impl : IMyInterface, IDisposable
{        
 public uint Start()
 {
 return 0;
 }
}
```

Additionally, I've enabled "Register for COM interop" in the project's build properties.  The next step to allow a Win32 app (actually an MFC app) to use it is I think to generate a .tlb for the assembly.  I'm doing this with the following post-build command:

> "$(FrameworkSdkDir)\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\tlbexp.exe"
> "$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetName).tlb" /win32

I see the .tlb in the build folder and then proceed to add it to the MFC project, right clicking it and setting it to Item Type: MIDL tool.  When I then build this project, I get the following warnings and errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: My_Dll_Test_MFC, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------ 
1>Processing ..\My_Dll\bin\x86\Debug\My_Dll.tlb 1>My_Dll.tlb 
1>..\My_Dll\bin\x86\Debug\My_Dll.tlb(1): warning C4335: Mac file format detected: please convert the source file to either DOS or UNIX format 
1>..\My_Dll\bin\x86\Debug\My_Dll.tlb(1): error MIDL2025: syntax error : expecting an interface name or DispatchInterfaceName or CoclassName or ModuleName or LibraryName or ContractName or a type specification near "MSFT" 
1>..\My_Dll\bin\x86\Debug\My_Dll.tlb(1): error MIDL2026: cannot recover from earlier syntax errors; aborting compilation 1>Done building project "My_Dll_Test_MFC.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

What mistake have I made here?

Comment: I do not work with COM in C++ for a while, but as I remember, the MIDL need the idl input, not the tlb. To consume the tlb in your C++ project, you need #import directive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Oh boy, I knew it would be something dumb.  I removed the tlb (you're right, it needs idl) and used the #import directive with raw_interfaces_only and it's all built.  Can you add as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use MIDL with a tlb (the MIDL need the idl input, not the tlb). To consume the tlb in your C++ project, you just need [#import directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-160)